# Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, oauth-2.0

I'm building a web app using MERN. Anytime I try to login using google login I get the same error. My Code for the button is included here:

```
      </Button>
      <GoogleLogin
      clientId ="x"
      render={(renderProps) => (
        <Button 
        className={classes.googleButton} 
        color='primary' 
        fullWidth 
        onClick={renderProps.onClick} 
        disabled={renderProps.disabled} 
        startIcon={<Icon/>} 
        variant="contained">
          Google Sign In
        </Button>
      )}
      onSuccess={googleSuccess}
      onFailure={googleFailure}
      cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
```

I don't know why this happens every time. I've also tried changing my cross origin settings in my index.html but this hasn't worked.